# Why is AngularJS selectpicker giving me a string when I'm expecting a hash?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select
        selectpicker
        ng-model="itemSelected" >
            <option
            ng-repeat="human in data"
            value="{{human}}" data-subtext="{{human.desc}}">{{human.name}}</option>
        </select>

        <p>--{{itemSelected}}--</p>
        <p>=={{itemSelected.name}}==</p>
            <p>##{{itemSelected.desc}}##</p>
    </div>


</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.itemSelected = '';
    $scope.data = [
        { 'name': 'Bob', 'desc': 'Words about Bob' },
        { 'name': 'Chris', 'desc': 'Words about Chris' },
        { 'name': 'Mary', 'desc': 'Words about Mary' }
    ];
}]);

myApp.directive('selectpicker', function( $timeout ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            $timeout ( function () {
                scope.$apply( function(){
                    element.selectpicker({ showSubtext:true });
                });

                scope.$watch('itemSelected', function( newValue, old ){
                    console.log( 'selected ', newValue );
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NoahRodenbeek/42pcux4p/

I'm pretty new to Angular, I'm sure I'm calling my ng-repeat incorrectly but every variation I've tried has failed. The result I am getting is the string form of my hash, which is frustrating. It's like Angular is mocking me, which I respect, but I would like to get passed this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could always use `angular.fromJson()` to parse it back into an object. http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/yydnx474/ Normally you'd use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` for a select but you can't set the subtext with `ng-options`.

Comment: Nice, I think that should work just fine for me. I set the watch in the directive, is fromJson something I can use down there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your value is being forced into a string here

```
value="{{human}}" data-subtext="{{human.desc}}">{{human.name}}</option>
```

Instead you could use the index as the value and then dereference it

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42pcux4p/4/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select selectpicker ng-model="itemSelected">
            <option ng-repeat="human in data" value="{{$index}}" data-subtext="{{human.desc}}">{{human.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <p>--{{itemSelected}}--</p>
        <p>=={{getName()}}==</p>
        <p>##{{getDesc()}}##</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.itemSelected = '';
    $scope.idx = 0;
    $scope.data = [{
        'name': 'Bob',
            'desc': 'Words about Bob'
    }, {
        'name': 'Chris',
            'desc': 'Words about Chris'
    }, {
        'name': 'Mary',
            'desc': 'Words about Mary'
    }];

    $scope.getName = function () {
        if ($scope.idx) return $scope.data[$scope.idx].name
        else return ''
    };
    $scope.getDesc = function () {
        if ($scope.idx) return $scope.data[$scope.idx].desc
        else return ''
    };

}]);

myApp.directive('selectpicker', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    element.selectpicker({
                        showSubtext: true
                    });
                });

                scope.$watch('itemSelected', function (newValue, old) {
                    scope.idx = newValue
                    console.log('selected ', newValue);
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Nice, that's a great idea! And I can just use the itemSelected as the hash index directly http://jsfiddle.net/NoahRodenbeek/42pcux4p/6/